# Is there any way to disable a calculation field?

Tags: cognito-forms

It would be nice if users were not mislead into thinking they could change totals.

Answer (score 0):

For other newbees.  I figured out that I can use a Content field.  When using a Content field you can insert other hidden fields which contain calculations.  Not as simple as having a "disable" property, but its useable.